I fell in love with you (from) the moment I

I fell in love with you the moment I saw you.

I fell in love with you from the moment I saw you.


Are these sentences correct? If so, is there any difference in meaning between them?

1 is a sudden, instant thing that happened when you saw them, 2 is something that started at that moment, and grew or developed after that.

from the moment works only with a process that begins and is understood to extend in time.  This is not a good sentence:  The chair collapsed from the moment I sat it in.  Your second sentence would work better with "began falling in love with you".

@TimR - an interesting discussion could be had about whether 'falling in love' necessarily happens in an instant or takes a while.

@MichaelHarvey I'm willing to accept the experience could go either way, but would say that if you want to express the takes-a-while experience in terms of when it all began,  as in from the moment I saw you,  "began falling" or "started to fall" would be better than "fell"  because those forms express the aspect more clearly.

it makes more sense to say I loved you from the moment I saw you

They have slightly different  meanings as Michael has described.
In (1), the moment I saw you is a time adjunct answering when? The moment tells us that the feeling developed suddenly.
In (2), the preposition phrase from the moment I saw you is also a time adjunct.  It answers the question from when? In this case, the feeling developed gradually.

But I would say that they are essentially identical in meaning. And for me the gradual development of the feeling is not absolutely required for (2) to be used.
